# There is a croll bar but there is nothing to see

Tags: css

I'm setting up a new page. In the CFM after /head, I have a /body and then a /div for my full page background followed by various forms and tables. Using CSS, I have moved said forms and tables up the page so that nothing extends beyond the bottom of the vertical scroll bar which is 1/3 up from the page bottom. When I scroll down, the background moves up and there is nothing to see and when I use Firefox Inspector, the only things extending beyond the scroll bar is html and body. Their css setting are "height: 100%;". So, why the scroll bar? ps. I'm pretty new to this....

Comment: Hard to say what the issue could be based on the info you have provided. Could be any of a number of things. Please update your question with some actual HTML and CSS that you're using that demonstrates the issue. Otherwise any answers you may get would just be guesses.

Comment: Fair comment. There is just so much code, I didn't know what to put up. Your point made me go back and experiment some more and see if I can refine the question and/or the code to show.

Comment: So, what I have is what I believe is a very basic newbie question. I'm building a web page and have created 3 tables. The third table is half on the page and half off but the scroll bar can be used to see the lower portion. Say I use CSS to move the table further up the page, should that cause the scroll bar to disappear even though the "volume" of the tables is still greater than the page size?

Comment: If your content fits in the page without having to scroll, the scroll bar should disappear, yes. But there are things that can affect that. If your last table has `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` that sticks out past the bottom of the page, for example, then you'd still be able to scroll. Or if there's a `min-height` on something that causes it to stick out past the bottom of the page even though there's nothing to see. Or if your CSS says `overflow: scroll` rather than `overflow: auto`. Again, we really need to see your actual code.

Comment: I don't want a scroll bar so I'm curious as to what "If your content fits in the page..." means.

Comment: Experimenting further...if my css contains: html, body
{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
} and I add in forms and tables until one sits across the bottom of the page, scrollbars do not appear and I can use CSS to move it up to be fully visible. This solves my problem.